# django REST combining 2 model views form for json curl

Tags: python, json, django, rest, curl

I have models:

```
class Emp(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)

class Enquiry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="products") 
    referred_by_emp = models.ForeignKey(
        Emp,related_name='ref_emp',
        null=True,blank=True,
        )
```

The serializer classes:

```
class ReferrerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Emp
        fields = (
            'full_name','mobile','email',
            )

class EnquirySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Enquiry
        fields = (
            'name','mobile','email',
            'products',
            'referred_by_emp',
            )
```

I wish to get the attributes of Emp i.e full_name, mobile, email in the form while entering the Enquiry details. The views for the 2 models:

```
class RefViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Emp instances to be viewed or edited.
    """
    model = Emp
    queryset = Emp.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReferrerSerializer

class EnquiryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        """
        API endpoint that allows Enquiry instances to be viewed or edited.
        """
        model = Enquiry
        queryset = Enquiry.objects.all()
        serializer_class = EnquirySerializer
```

While entering the Enquiry details in the django REST api, I wish to capture the Emp details also and submit the form. And the details should be captured in the respective models. How can this be achieved? I am new to django's REST Api and didn't find a proper way of doing it. Plz guide me with detailed code to achieve this. I tried itertools.chain, but perhaps didn't use it correctly Further I would like to invoke the curl command for the same.Thanx in advance 
Using django 1.6.5

Comment: You want to submit one json blob that populates both models? or fill in Enquiry from existing Emp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/992401/krs submit one json blob that populates both models

Answer (score 1):

Ok  this is not something i recommend doing, but I've have been there when it just has to happen.

```
class ReferrerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Emp
        fields = ('full_name','mobile','email')


class EnquirySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Enquiry
        fields = ('name','mobile','email','products',)


# As the fields doesn't already exist you can 'copy' them into the serializer

EnquirySerializer.base_fields["full_name"] = ReferrerSerializer().fields["full_name"]            


# Then in the view we can create another model instance.
# you should use the Serializer or a Form class and not save the data directly to a Emp instance here but i left that out for clarity.

class SomeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Enquiry

    # post() should only handle new/create calls, but if you want it more clear you can override create() instead.
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.emp_data = {}
        self.emp_data["full_name"] = self.request.DATA.pop("full_name")
        return super(SomeViewSet, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
       emp = Emp.objects.create(**self.emp_data)
       obj.referred_by_emp = emp
       return obj
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/992401/krs but I want the form of Enquiry as well as Emp to be displayed simultaneously, so that the Emp details can also be added. How do I do it?

Comment: Add the fields as in the P.S at the end of my post, then pop() then from the data in post(). I update the example with this usage.

Comment: Exception: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "state-detail' You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. These are other foreignkey fields in the Enquiry model like State, Country, which are non-mandatory! How do I resolve this @http://stackoverflow.com/users/992401/krs. Thx for your efforts in advance